# Vuetify overlay overlays the drawer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a navbar for Vue application, I'm using Vuetify, on large screen there is toolbar, on small there is hamburger icon which opens the navigation drawer.

It works, but there is an overlay that comes in front of drawer and I can't change a page.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar dark>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="hidden-md-and-up" @click="sidebar = !sidebar"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-navigation-drawer v-model="sidebar" app>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in menuItems" exact :key="i" :to="item.path">{{item.title}}</v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
      <v-toolbar-title>Jobify</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn text v-for="item in menuItems" :key="item.title">
          <router-link :to="item.path">{{item.title}}</router-link>
        </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-app-bar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      sidebar: false,
      menuItems: [
        { path: "/jobs", name: "jobs", title: "Jobs" },
        { path: "/companies", name: "companies", title: "Companies" },
        { path: "/jobs/new", name: "new-job", title: "Add job" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Only Vuetify components that I'm using are here, there is, actually, `v-app` in App component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add `hide-overlay` prop to the `v-navigation-drawer` component in order to hide the overlay :

```
 <v-navigation-drawer v-model="sidebar" app hide-overlay >
```

Comment: What if I still want to show the overlay over everything except the drawer?

Comment: by default the drawer is not affected by the overlay